# Applying more than Two Filter to DataFrame with & operator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a df and I want to apply multiple filtering that df.

```
...
    def applyFilter(self):
        ## 1st Condition
        if self.col1_lineEdit.text() != "":
            self.filter_col1 = (self.myDataFrame['col1'] == self.col1_lineEdit.text())
        else:
            self.filter_col1 = [True] * len(self.myDataFrame) # If line edit is empty, take all values.

        if self.col2_lineEdit.text() != "":
            self.filter_col2 = (self.myDataFrame['col2'] == self.col2_lineEdit.text())
        else:
            self.filter_col2 = [True] * len(self.myDataFrame)

        if self.col3_lineEdit.text() != "":
            self.filter_col3 = (self.myDataFrame['col3'] == self.col3_lineEdit.text())
        else:
            self.filter_col3 = [True] * len(self.myDataFrame)

        ## 2nd conditions
        if self.col4_lineEdit.text() != "":
            self.filter_col4 = (self.myDataFrame['col4'] == self.col4_lineEdit.text())
        else:
            self.filter_col4 = [True] * len(self.myDataFrame)

        if self.col5_lineEdit.text() != "":
            self.filter_col5 = (self.myDataFrame['col5'] == self.col5_lineEdit.text())
        else:
            self.filter_col5 = [True] * len(self.myDataFrame)

        if self.col6_lineEdit.text() != "":
            self.filter_col6 = (self.myDataFrame['col6'] == self.col6_lineEdit.text())
        else:
            self.filter_col6 = [True] * len(self.myDataFrame)
...
```

this is my apply filter method. After that I used something like this;

```
self.filteredResult = self.myDataFrame[self.filter_col1 & self.filter_col2 & self.filter_col3 & self.filter_col4 & self.filter_col5 & self.filter_col6]
```

this is working only for **col1 and col2** filtering. However if I change the formula like this (disable first operand wih **and**) ;

```
self.filteredResult = self.myDataFrame[self.filter_col1 and self.filter_col2 & self.filter_col3 & self.filter_col4 & self.filter_col5 & self.filter_col6]
```

it works for col2 and col3. So I tried to debug the code, then I got an error like this;

*self.filteredResult = self.myDataFrame[self.filter_col1 & self.filter_col2 & self.filter_col3 & self.filter_col4 & self.filter_col5 & self.filter_col6]
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'***

When I search the problem on the internet, every solution was applying two filters not more. If I apply two filters there is no problem. However I need to apply 6 filters. I also serached and tried some soluiton with error code. Also I got nothing. Can you help me, or say anything about the problem?

Edit: I didnt understand the error. If & operand is not allowed to use on list. Why the first and second can apply not the others?

**Important Edit : I forgot to say this; if I apply filter first or second column, I can apply the other filters. (in this case)**

```
self.filteredResult = self.myDataFrame[self.filter_col1 & self.filter_col2 & self.filter_col3 & self.filter_col4 & self.filter_col5 & self.filter_col6]
```

As far as I understand, program takes to compare the first two filters with & operand, then the other filters depends on these filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I had to add a column that had no effect on the results but had to trick filter. So I add to my table an addition column which named **ALL** and filled with **ALL** parameter. Then i edited my filter as;

```
self.filteredResult = self.myDataFrame[(self.myDataFrame['ALL'] == "ALL") & self.filter_col1 & self.filter_col2 & self.filter_col3 & self.filter_col4 & self.filter_col5 & self.filter_col6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a parenthesis in each conditions:

```
self.filteredResult = self.myDataFrame[(self.filter_col1) & (self.filter_col2) & (self.filter_col3) & (self.filter_col4) & (self.filter_col5) & (self.filter_col6)]
```

Comment: I saw this solution on the internet, and I tried but nothing changed. again it says; **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'**

Comment: Will self.filter_col1 give either True or False?

Comment: My method is, if col1 line edit (or any other) is empty returns True to take all values from that column. No column is NULL(NaN) btw. If you write anything in the corresponding lineEdit, it will filter according to that value. Btw can you look at my importtant update in the question, maybe that will clearify a bit more about problem.

Comment: Is it correct that self.filter_col1 etc. can also contain NULL?

Comment: No, every column has something

Comment: self.myDataFrame[(self.filter_col1) & (self.filter_col2) ] each of the conditions inside the parenthesis can only contain True or False to work regardless if there are 2 or more conditions.

Comment: So I cannot able to compare more than 2 filter?

Comment: You can, however the filter can only have a value of either True or False.